# perl handling error if remote node is not exist

Tags: perl

I am using Net::Telnet module with my perl script. I give a list of routers to this script to login and retrieve output from those nodes.

Out of those three nodes i mentioned one node in middle of list which is not pingable or it really not exist on network.

For example consider below list of nodes

```
brtm502

biad502

bjae500
```

out of which `biad502` is not pingable (or not exist on network).

when I run this script it stops and throwing below output and die at that point.

```
"unknown remote host: biad502 at unix-gsr-manual.pl line 70"
```

My requirement.

1/ Even if some node is not available in network the script should continue to next node and provide me output as expected excluding the node which is not on network.

I tried use below code but still same result.

```
$session->open("$node") ;

$session->errmode("return");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the errmode after you tell Net::Telnet to make the connection.  Either reverse the order or collapse the errmode setting into the ->open, using the extended invocation that you'll find in the documentation.

Comment: Oh my god! really this was really very quick and simplest solution. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Well, glancing at [the documentation](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aTelnet), you can do one of the following:

1. Change the `errmode` to something other than `die` (which is the default).
2. Use an [`eval` block](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) to see if the connection was successful (and to throw a warning and do whatever else you want if the connection was not successful).
3. Use a CPAN module such as [`Try::Tiny`](http://p3rl.org/Try%3a%3aTiny) or [`TryCatch`](http://p3rl.org/TryCatch) to catch the exception and not `die` as a result.